# "Painting the plains with silverwares"

Tags: meaning, usage

> Painting the plains with silverwares

Can you use painting to mean metaphorically that someone just threw a bunch of silverwares on a plains?

I also see sentences like:

> Painted the skies with gold

So I am wondering if it's a similar usage. Because gold I believe refers to an object just like silverwares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I would say "painted the plains with silverware" (not silverwares!) is **not** idiomatic.

The phrase "painted the skies with gold," or [as John Denver put it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vrEljMfXYo)

> Dark and dusty, painted on the sky

refers to the painting of a *color* in the sky, not an object.

In your example I might say "scattered silverware across the plains."